# Page flashes on basic jQuery scroll to element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a link that when clicked, scrolls downwards to an element.

Each time I test the click, the page inconsistently may flash before scrolling.

**The link:**

```
<a id="continue_scroll" href="#welcome">Continue / Scroll</span></a>
```

**The element being scrolled to:**

```
<h2 id="welcome">WELCOME</h2>
```

**The jQuery:**

```
jQuery(function($){     
    $("#continue_scroll").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#welcome").offset().top
        }, 2000);
    });   
});
```

**Behaviour:** Occurs when I refresh the page and click the continue link in succession or intermittently clicking elsewhere before/after. The behaviour is inconsistent.

Can anyone identify what's causing this and what the corresponding solution might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prevent the default action of the anchor (which is to jump immediately to the href'ed element)

```
jQuery(function($){     
    $("#continue_scroll").click(function(e) { <!-- add a reference to the event here -->
        e.preventDefault(); <!-- prevent the default action of the event -->
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#welcome").offset().top
        }, 2000);
    });   
});
```

The flash you see is the page scrolling immediately to `#welcome` before jQuery takes over and scrolls to the element again with an animation

Comment: Thank you for this working solution. I overlooked the simple in assuming the issue was more complex or slider related.